# If $G\simeq H$ and $d||G|$ then both $G$ and $H$ have the same number of elements of order $d$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In the book "Advanced modern algebra" written by J. Rotman there is the following exercise:

**Exercise:** Prove that if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic groups then for every divisor $d$ of $|G|$, both $G$ and $H$ have the same number of elements of order $d$.

**My Atempt:** Suppose $f:G\longrightarrow H$ is an isomorphism and define $G_d=\{g\in G: o(g)=d\}$ and $H_d=\{h\in H: o(h)=d\}$. Here $o(x)$ means order of $x$. Consider the map, $$\varphi:G_d\longrightarrow H_d,\ g\mapsto f(g).$$ This map is well define for an isomorphism preserve order. It is easy verified $\varphi$ is a bijection from what the result would follow.

However, the argument above has a flaw because I haven't used the fact $d||G|$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The proof is fine. The thing is, if $d$ is not a divisor of the order of the group, then the associated subset $G_d$ is empty.

Comment: Great, thanks =)